# when trying to call a function, i got "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Tags: python

After searching through multiple forums i still cant find an answer that i understand. I am making a simple text game and when writing a part of it i got this: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.". Heres the code:

```
def tutorial():
    print ("In this game your objective is to make out alive from the haunted house of torture.")
    print ("In each round, you will be faced with 3 questions, 3 choices each question.")
    print ("Now, are you ready to begin? (Yes or No)")
    begin = input()
    if begin == "No":
        def redo():
            print ("Oh, than would you like to start the tutorial all over again?(Yes or No)")
            stog = input()
            if stog == "No":
                redo()
            if stog == "Yes":
                tutorial()

def start():
    print ("Hello! Would you like to start the tutorial? (Yes or No)")
    tutorial = input()
    if tutorial == "No":
        print ("Okay than, lets begin!!")
        start()
    if tutorial == "Yes":
        print ("Okay than, lets start the tutorial!!")
        tutorial()

start()
```

the exact error message i got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tester2.py", line 29, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tester2.py", line 23, in start
    tutorial()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

i get the error after saying "yes" to the first question. help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this: `if begin == "No": def redo():` is not right.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: You have overwritten `tutorial` variable to a string in your `start` function.

Comment: The problem is that you redefined `tutorial`  You are using it as a function and as a string.

Comment: OH!! i get it now! haha i made tutorial the name of two different things lol. thanks! X'D

Answer (score 1):

```
def start():
    print ("Hello! Would you like to start the tutorial? (Yes or No)")
    tutorial = input() #warning, a bad variable name, same with outer 
                       #function, will overwrite the name.
    if tutorial == "No":
        print ("Okay than, lets begin!!")
        start()
    if tutorial == "Yes":
        print ("Okay than, lets start the tutorial!!")
        tutorial()  # error, tutorial is a string now, it is not callable
```